# Find optimal $k$ such that $(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i(x_i^2-y_i^2))^2\le k^2\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-y_i)^2$, with $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2, \sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2\le1$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $\{a_i\}$ be $n$ real numbers.
It can be shown that there is $k\ge 0$ such that
for all $x_i,y_i\in\mathbb{R}$ satisfying
$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\le 1$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2\le 1$,
$$
(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i(x_i^2-y_i^2))^2\le k^2 \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-y_i)^2.
$$
I proved the above with $k=2\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n {a_i^2}}$,
but I suspect that $k=2\max\{|a_i|\}$ is the optimal value for $k$. I struggle to produce a proof.

Comment: Try first for $n=1.$ Then extend to any $n,$ using CS. And you are not asked for "an optimal value".

Comment: @AnneBauval I actually managed to prove the existence of $k$, but now I would like to find the optimal $k$. Changed the question a bit.

Comment: Again: instead (or before) proving $k=2\max\{a_i\}$ is "an optimal value", prove it *is* a value. Try when all $a_i$'s are equal.

Comment: @AnneBauval It doesn't seem that the equality is always attainable for $k=2\max\{|a_i|\}$. I'm considering the quotient $(\sum a(x^2-y^2))^2/(\sum (x-y)^2)$, but I don't know how to maximize this quotient.

Comment: by using C-S, $k^2\geq\sum a_i^2(x_i+y_i)^2$ is sufficient for above inequality to hold. And from it you can show $k^2\geq 4\max a_i^2$ would be sufficient. It remains to check the choice $x_i=1, y_i=1-\epsilon$ where $i$ is the index for maximal $a_i$ to justify your optimal argument.

Comment: @OolongMilktea Fine! Won't you type it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Oolong Milktea does not seem to want to post a full-fledged solution here, I would answer the question myself following their idea.

---

If all $a_i$ are $0$, then clearly $k=0$ is the optimal value.
Otherwise, there is $a_j$ such that $|a_j|=\max\{|a_i|\}>0$.
Choose $k:=2|a_j|$.
Then
$$
\begin{align*}
\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i(x_i^2-y_i^2) \right)^2 
&= \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i(x_i+y_i)(x_i-y_i) \right)^2 \\
&\le \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i^2(x_i+y_i)^2 \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-y_i)^2 
& \text{Cauchy's inequality} \\
&= a_j^2 \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{a_i^2}{a_j^2} (x_i+y_i)^2 \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-y_i)^2 
& a_j\neq 0\\
&\le a_j^2 \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i+y_i)^2 \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-y_i)^2 
& \forall i:a_j^2\ge a_i^2\\
&\le a_j^2 \left( \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^2} + \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i^2}  \right)^2 \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-y_i)^2
& \text{Triangle inequality} \\
&\le 4a_j^2 \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-y_i)^2
& \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^2 \le 1,\sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i^2\le 1 \\
&= k^2 \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-y_i)^2.
\end{align*}
$$
We now prove that $k$ is optimal.
Let $0<r<1$.
Choose $x_j:=1$ and $y_j:=1-r$, and all other $x_i,y_i:=0$.
Then
$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{r\to 0^+} \frac{(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i(x_i^2-y_i^2))^2}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-y_i)^2}
&= \lim_{r\to 0^+} \frac{a_j^2(1-(1-r)^2)^2}{r^2} \\
&= 4a_j^2 \\
&= k^2.
\end{align*}
$$
This then shows that
$$
k^2=\sup\left\{\frac{(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i(x_i^2-y_i^2))^2}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-y_i)^2}:x_i,y_i\in\mathbb{R};\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2\le 1,\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i^2\le 1 ;\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-y_i)^2\neq 0\right\},
$$
so $k$ is optimal.